# Mockito - mock object inside method

Tags: java, tdd, junit4, mockito

I have a method that return the list of vehicles. Like this:

```
 public List<Vehicle> getVehicles() {

        List<Vehicle> vehicles=vehicleDAO.getAllVehicles();

        for (Vehicle v : vehicles){//NullPointerException
            //some bussines logic...
        }       
        return vehicles;

}
```

And here is my test:

```
@Test
public void testShowVehicles() {
    when(vehicleDAO.getAllVehicles()).thenReturn(listVehiclesMock);
    List<Vehicle> vehicles= service.getVehicles();//NullPointerException
    assertEquals(listVehicleMock, vehicles);
}
```

When I run it I get NullPointerException because Vehicle does not exists.
When I have old fashion for loop it passes the test, but now I replaced with forEach loop I get error in test.
So how would I mock the object Vehicle?

Answer (score 2):

For each loop uses `iterator()` method of the given `Iterable`. An iterator obtained that way is then used to iterate over the collection. Unfortunately, this method of the mocked list  returns null, which causes `NullPointerException`. To use for each loop syntax you have to bind `iterator()` method to result as well.

Comment: Can you give some tips how would I bind `iterator()` to the test.

Comment: Instead of returning a mocked list from a mock object, it might be easier returning an actual list with a single Vehicle object. This way, you won't have to write additional _when_ clauses and avoid NullPointerException within your business logic.

Comment: Is this ok that I return actual list instead of mocked list?

Comment: Yes, it's fine to return an actual list instead of a mock.  There's nothing about the List class that needs to be faked in order to test your class.